# Multiple Nginx master process

Tags: nginx

When i run my nginx server with command:

```
/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

I have two master process

```
root     11632  2.6  0.1  76164  1372 ?        Ss   01:30   0:06 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
www      14515  3.0 24.0 319920 245060 ?       S    01:35   0:00 nginx: worker process
www      14516  3.0 24.0 319920 245060 ?       S    01:35   0:00 nginx: worker process
www      14517  3.0 24.0 319920 245232 ?       S    01:35   0:00 nginx: worker process
www      14518  0.0  6.5 319920 66544 ?        R    01:35   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

A part of my nginx.conf:

```
user  www www;

worker_processes 4;
error_log  /data/logs/nginx_error.log  crit;
pid        /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 600000;

events
{
  use epoll;
  worker_connections 600000;
}
```

When worker_processes less than 4, the `ps aux | grep nginx | grep -v grep` looks good. If worker_process is 4, it will have two master processes.

Comment: You should have only one master process per *nginx* instance. Stop it, and kill any residual process. Restart it.

Comment: I have stop nginx and killed the process, but when i restart it, it also have multiple master process.

Comment: Maybe nginx is started both as a `/etc/init.d/nginx` start script, and also as a `/etc/init` service..

Comment: Maybe you have a docker container also running nginx